# Evaluate $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos x}{2x^2 + 1} \,\mathrm{d}x$ using complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, complex-integration

I've been having trouble to solve the following integral using complex analysis, so if someone could give a tip how to get it done?

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos x}{2x^2 + 1} \,\mathrm{d}x$$

**Attempt:** I replaced $\cos x$ with $(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})/2$, and then I introduced a new complex variable $z = e^{i x}$. From this relationship I replaced $x$ by taking the natural log of both sides, and then I got a complex integral along a closed curve $| z | = 1$ and that is it.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I replaced cos x with (e^(i x) + e^(i x))/2, and then I introduced a new complex variable z = e^(i x), and from this relationship I replaced x by taking the natural log of both sides, and then I get a complex integral along a closed curve | z | = 1 and that is it

Comment: Any reason to believe a solution exists? $\int_0^{2 \pi}$ is not quite the same as $\int_0^\infty$

Comment: [The solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+%28cos+x%29%2F%282x%5E2%2B1%29+from+0+to+2pi) is complicated.